# Cat 6 network cable not working

Tags: networking, cable, cabling

During some refurbishment, I have recently added a cat 6 cable around a room in order to add wireless access point. However, it is not working: this is the setup that I was aiming for:

```
Modem/Router 
-> CAT5 (this was aleady there but not in the right place, hence I needed the additional cables)
-> RJ45 Coupler 
-> CAT6
-> Faceplate 
-> CAT 5 patch
-> Wireless Access Point.
```

This, however, does work:

```
Modem/Router
-> CAT5
-> Wireless Access Point
```

As does this:

```
Modem/Router (in Living Room)
-> CAT5
-> RJ45 Coupler
-> CAT5
-> Wireless Access Point
```

So I suspect it is due to the CAT 6 cable. I crimped the plug and added the faceplate termination myself and tested it then with cable tester and says everything is OK but when I connect the router as per the above, it does not work. I suspect I have messed up the ends of the cable but I am not sure how to resolve this. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Easiest to remake the cables. Otherwise you need a cable tester to determine the fault.

Comment: Did you crimp as twisted pair?

Comment: I've tried to make your question a little easier to read by formatting it. If I have gone too far please revert the edits.

Comment: Thanks Burgi - apologies, I am new at this.

Comment: @ Spikey_Richie & John: I have a basic cable tester which checks the mapping and continuity which says it's ok.  Yes, I crimped as twisted pair (B) and wired the faceplate the same. Is it possible for the tester to say it is ok but notwork because of dodgy workmanship or noise or such the like?

Comment: See https://www.lanshack.com/make_cat_6_cable.aspx for correct pinout.

Comment: I'm surprised no one mentioned that "**RJ-45** couplers" are trash 99% of the time... They usually do not meet any of the requirements for Ethernet past 10/100mbps. If you crack it open you will most likely find straight pins going to each side (not twisted pair). You would be better off using two cat-6 wall jack inserts with 6-12" of cat-6 to inter-connect them. I have never seen one of these adapters pass testing on my fluke networks cable analyzer, even with them in-between short patch cables...

Comment: Have you crimped the plug in accordance with TIA/EIA 568A or B specs?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. @Tim_Stewart was right on this one, it was a dodgy RJ-45 coupler - the way the cable was lying was pulling it away from the pins. Switched it out for a different coupler and everything works. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!